# Why does String.Format fail to escape characters when the string is in a resource?

Tags: c#, string, .net-4.5, string-formatting

```
var result1 = String.Format("Hello\n\t{0}\n\n", "Bill");
// MyResource.FormatMe contains the same text: Hello\n\t{0}\n\n
var result2 = String.Format(MyResource.FormatMe, "Bill");
```

result1 is as expected:

```
"Hello
    Bill

"
```

result2 is not:

```
Hello\n\tBill\n\n
```

Why is `String.Format` not escaping escape characters when the format string comes from a resource?

Comment: Anything that isn't inside an actual string in the code is taken literally, so the string would be stored as `Hello\n\t{0}\n\n` literally, as opposed to `Hello<newline><tab>{0}<newline><newline>`. You'll have to unescape the string manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`String.Format` does not escape anything. It's the compiler, that processes `\n`, `\t` and other escape sequences in string literals into something else (that is, if you look at the binary, produced by compiler and search for your string, you will not find literal `\` character followed by `n` there, but actual bytes for line break characters instead). So anything that does not exist as a string literal in your code will not have escape sequences processed.

You can easily preprocess your strings to change `\n` and `\t` into actual line breaks and tabs:

```
string result2_format = MyResource.FormatMe.Replace("\\n", "\n").Replace("\\t", "\t");
```